# How to reverse a MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need to reverse my output and I can't do it by switching the `ORDER BY` clause.

This code is getting the last 12 months, but I need to display them in the opposite order. Right now it has October first, but I need it to come last. If I switched to `ORDER BY DATE ASC` then I would get the wrong months.

My code is this:

```
<?php
$result2 = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "SELECT SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)
        FROM royalties 
        GROUP BY DATE
        ORDER BY DATE DESC
        LIMIT 12"
);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo number_format($row2[0], 2, '.', '') . ', ';
}?>
```

Comment: You could add a `WHERE` clause that only matches dates in the past 12 months, and then reverse the `ORDER BY`. This will not only solve the order problem, but should make the query faster since it doesn't have to process the entire table.

Comment: @Barmar You should add that as an answer...

Comment: What is the type of your `date` column? Is it a date, or just a string  like `YYYY-MM`? How is it that grouping by date just returns one row per month, rather than rows for each day in the month?

Comment: its a string, YYYY-MM. And it is one row per month, giving me the monthly total

Comment: Shouldn't be tagged as PHP as it only involves MySQL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just wrap your query in another select and reverse the `order by`:

```
SELECT res
FROM (
  SELECT `date`,SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE) AS res
  FROM royalties
  GROUP BY `date`
  ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 12
  ) a
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now, mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given